# Metodo get me regresa un null

Tags: java, javafx, get, set

estaba haciendo un programa en javafx y me tope con un problema al llamar la funcion getUsuario() en mi otra clase, ya que al correr el programa me lo regresa como null, no se si tenga que ver algo con el metodo initialize() de fx.

```java
    public class FXMLloginController implements Initializable {

        conexion baseDatos = new conexion().conectar();
        ObservableList<String> lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<String> lista1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<String> lista2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        @FXML
        private TextField matricula;

        @FXML
        private TextField contra;
        @FXML
        private Button Acceder;
        private Stage primarystage;
        private BorderPane rootlayout;

        private String contrasenia = null;
        private String Usuario = null;

        //metodos set y get
        public String getUsuario() {
            return Usuario;
        }

        public void setUsuario(String Usuario) {
            this.Usuario = Usuario;
        }


        public void iniciarsesion() {
            ResultSet rs = baseDatos.consultar("SELECT * FROM Usuarios");
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        if (rs.getString("matricula") == null ? matricula.getText() == null : rs.getString("matricula").equals(matricula.getText())) {
                            System.out.println("encontrado");
                            this.Usuario = rs.getString("matricula");
                            this.contrasenia = rs.getString("contrasenia");
                            System.out.println("Esta es contraseña"+contrasenia + "esta es usuario"+Usuario);
                            //regreso el valor del usuario con set 

                            setUsuario(Usuario);`
                            try {
                                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("PagPrincipal.fxml"));
                                Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                                Stage stage = new Stage();
                                stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
                                Stage stage1 = (Stage) Acceder.getScene().getWindow(); //Cerrar ventana anterior
                                stage1.close(); //esta tambien
                                stage.setMaximized(true);
                                stage.show();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        //+ " " + rs.getString("Nombre")+" "+rs.getString("ApePat")+rs.getString("ApeMat")
                    }
                    if (contrasenia == null) {
                        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "El Usuario o contraseña no han sido encontrados.", ButtonType.CLOSE);
                        alert.showAndWait();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    //Logger.getLogger(FXMLVentasController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }


        @FXML
        void BottonAcceder(ActionEvent event) {
            iniciarsesion();

        }


        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            // TODO

        }

    }
```

Esta es mi otra clase donde deben pasar los usuarios y contraseña, en este caso solo intento pasar el usuario

```java
    public class PagPrincipalController implements Initializable {
    conexion baseDatos = new conexion().conectar();

        /**
         * Initializes the controller class.
         */

        @FXML
        private Label nombre;
        @FXML
        private Label labelfecha;
        @FXML
        private Button ResExambtn;

        @FXML
        private Button Cerrarsesionbtn;

        @FXML
        private ChoiceBox comboboxcursos;

        @FXML
        private Button aceptarbtn;

        @FXML
        void btnResAnt(ActionEvent event) {

        }

        @FXML
        void btnaceptar(ActionEvent event) {
            String opc = null;
            System.out.println(comboboxcursos.getValue().toString());
            opc = comboboxcursos.getValue().toString();
            switch (opc) {
                case "PHQ-2-5-2019":
                    System.out.println("funciono");
                    try {
                        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ExamenPHQ_2.fxml"));
                        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                        Stage stage = new Stage();
                        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
                        Stage stage1 = (Stage) aceptarbtn.getScene().getWindow(); //Cerrar ventana anterior
                        stage1.close(); //esta tambien
                        stage.setMaximized(true);
                        stage.show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                case "SMP-03_52019":
                    System.out.println("funciono2");
                    break;

            }
        }

        @FXML
        void btncerrarsesion(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLlogin.fxml"));
                        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                        Stage stage = new Stage();
                        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
                        Stage stage1 = (Stage) Cerrarsesionbtn.getScene().getWindow(); //Cerrar ventana anterior
                        stage1.close(); //esta tambien
                        stage.setMaximized(true);
                        stage.show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            // TODO
            hora();
            combobox();
            datos();


        }

        public void hora() {
            java.util.Date fecha = new Date();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
            labelfecha.setText(dateFormat.format(fecha));
            System.out.println("Fecha: " + dateFormat.format(fecha));
        }

        public void combobox() {
            comboboxcursos.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    //"PHQ-2-5-2019", "SMP-03_52019", 
                    //new Separator(), "Save", "Save as"));
                    "PHQ-2-5-2019", "SMP-03_52019"));
            comboboxcursos.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Seleccione el Curso a Realizar"));
        }


     public void datos(){
            //me regresa null
            FXMLloginController login = new FXMLloginController();
            System.out.println(login.getUsuario());
        }
```

Debería tener como resultado el usuario introducido pero en vez de eso obtengo null. no se en que parte este fallando el código, si alguien puede asesorarme con esto se los agradecería

Comment: Seria necesario ver donde inicializas y/o le das los valores al objeto **login**, a simple vista te diria que getUsuario te esta devolviendo el valor por defecto de Usuario porque no le has dado ningun valor

Comment: hola , gracias por el comentario, acabo de actualizar la publicación con las declaraciones de las variables y demás métodos que tenia